# CR/LF generated by PBEWithMD5AndDES encryption?

Tags: encryption, encoding, base64

May the encryption string provided by PBEWithMD5AndDES and then Base64 encoded contain the CR and or LF characters?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the question Xarph, but please do specify the specific language/API, include as many tags as possible and use a question mark somewhere in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using java with Andorid SDK. I found that the command:

```
String s = Base64.encodeToString(enc, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

did line wrapping. It put LF chars into the output string.

I found that:

```
String s = Base64.encodeToString(enc, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

did not put the LF characters into the output string.

Answer (score 3):

Base64 is only printable characters.  However when it's used as a MIME type for email it's split into lines which are separated by CR-LF.

Comment: Your answer is of course correct (so +1) but I've created a longer answer that goes deeper into the question.

Answer (score 1):

PBEWithMD5AndDES returns binary data. PBE encryption is defined within the [PKCS#5 standard](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-5v2/pkcs5v2_1.pdf), and this standard does not have a dedicated base 64 encoding scheme. So the question becomes for which system you need to Base 64 encode the binary data. Wikipedia has a [nice section within the Base 64 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history) that explains the various forms.

You may encounter a PBE implementation that returns a Base 64, and the implementation does not mention which of the above schemes is used. In that case you need to somehow figure out which scheme is used. I would suggest searching for it, asking the community, looking at the source or if all fails, creating a set of tests on the output.

Fortunately you are pretty safe if you are decoding base 64 and you are ignoring all the white space. Note that some implementations are disregarding padding, so add it before decoding, if applicable.

If you perform the encoding base 64 yourself, I would strongly suggest to not output any whitespace, use only the default alphabet (with `'+'` and `'/'` signs) and always perform padding when required. After that you can always split the result and replace any non-standard character (especially the `'+'` and `'/'` signs of course), or remove the padding.